# How to fix network stack (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, networking

Attempting to simplify question here. My network connections on a Windows 7 machine are hosed.  Here are the symptoms:

1. In spite of being a member of HOME homegroup, other computers on LAN do not see PC.  However, the PC can see other computers on HOME.
2. security video server (Blue Iris), not visible from LAN or WAN (using port forwarding on Netgear R6220)
3. Logitech Media Server running on PC no longer visible by others on LAN.

I have uninstalled all software installed since the problem started and then used System Restore to restore back to what I think was a stable point.  Also ran `sfc /scannow` and found nothing.

Is there a way to fix the network stack without having to re-install the OS?

Comment: Hi, Check under                                                                                          Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings

Comment: Well you can reset Winsock (may or may not be the issue) with the command: *netsh winsock reset*. This doesn't come without a disclaimer though: Any registered (Layered Service Providers) LSPs for example will be removed and will not be put back unless the software that registered them does so again on update for example or is re-installed . That said, you may not have any installed as it's quite an old technology to inspect network traffic. Before doing so I would suggest run: *netsh winsock show catalog > catalog.txt* first to see what is registered and what you might need to re-install.