# Restore Windows 7 without re-installing

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore

Having had a network problem for a couple of months and finding no solution, I am faced with a full re-install of Windows 7.  Then I thought, wait, I have a full disk backup (using Shadowprotect) of the system from 2 months ago, when the system was fully functional.

Here is my plan:
1) Use Shadowprotect recovery environment to restore the 2 month-old backup to a disk.
2) re-install the programs that I had installed since then
3) Use the Shadoprotect 
explore backup command to mount a current backup and then copy all the new files that I have added since the 2-month-old backup and delete all the old files deleted since then.

Questions:
1) For this to fix the problem, I need to make sure that I don't "update" any of the system files or settings since the last working backup.
2) I need a command/program that will find all user data files in the current backup that were created between the date of the working backup and the current date and ALSO delete any files that had been deleted in that period.  I think Robocopy has a mode that will do this?
3) Avoid copying any system files that might have been corrupted during the period that may have caused the network problem in the first place.

Does this seem like it should work?  What command program do you recommend that would do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not familiar enough with Shadow Protect but I could solve your network problem so restoration is avoided

Comment: Ok.  How should I contact you?

Comment: You don't at least not directly.  I never help anyone in private I either help everyone with the problem or nobody

Comment: OK.  Well, here is my question, if you think it is general enough to answer:  https://superuser.com/questions/1181604/how-to-fix-network-stack-windows-7